# Web Application Legacy FCM Notifications Not Reaching My Android Phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

This is my first ever post so please forgive any newb stupidity. I have been trying to get this right for 6 days straight. I want to be able to trigger a notification on my android phone from my PC by running a php file sitting on my online server.

Between all the text and videos available on GCM, FCM legacy, FCM V1, and Firebase itself it has proven impossible to find a coherent example or tutorial on how to achieve this.

On the advice of "@Jay President at Visual Dynamics, Inc." I have reduced my code to the part I think is causing the balls-up.

Here goes: I'm succeeding in registering and saving an FCM token in my online MYSQL DB. I get the following and save it to MYSQL...

> {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fn2AxrA1DLI:APA*************************************G31","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BGwqbu2**************************************vCqSenne4KABWuGN6x3w","auth":"xasG3yCzA*************l7hA"}}

Now I want to use that token to send a very basic "Hello World" to the device that registered that token (my android phone). From my home computer I want to run a file that sends that "hello world". Here's the code of the file that's supposed to trigger the sending, keeping in mind the registration has been successful.

```
    <?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$posts = 
array(
    "subscription" => array(
        "endpoint" => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fn2AxrA1DLI:APA9**********************etc",
        "expirationTime" => null,
        "keys" => array(
            "p256dh"=>"BGwqbu2lNL7**********BWuGN6x3w",
            "auth" =>"xas*****************7hA"
        )
    ),
    "data" => $_GET["msg"],
    "applicationKeys" => array(
        "public" => "BBY6vTaImSYSLkhO-***********************",
        "private" => "HBcroD*****************************"
    )
);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key='. "AIzaSyAy******************K7xvha2GaA0");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($posts));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);?>
```

As it stands I don't get errors, the result just prints "to" to my screen and no notification on my phone.

I've read that I need to encrypt the message but I'm not sure whether that applies to legacy FCM. I have activated FCM on google developer console and created a project in Firebase and I did generate the public and private keys.

As you can see I'm pretty lost here and anyone who can point me in the right direction will have my son named after them!!!

Comment: Man, that's a lot of code for us to look through. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can condense the code, it may be easier to spot the issue and come up with a solution.

Comment: Thank @Jay. I've removed the two files that are actually giving me the results I want. It's just the sending that isn't working. I posted the subscription files only in case there was something in there that might have been causing the wrong subscription token, but after 6 days of reading, I'm rather certain that once the subscription token mentions "fcm" it's prob ok.